# quotes are inserting by PDO

Tags: pdo

im using PDO for my insert query like below:

```
$stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`name`) VALUES (:name)");
$stmt->execute(array(":name"=>$_POST['name']));
```

but when user input includes quotes or double quotes and etc,those bad parameters are still inserting in my database!
where is my mistake?

Comment: Qoutes are legal chars. You have no char filter there.

Comment: am i vulnerable for sql injection? @panther

Comment: Your code is not open to SQL Injection because you are using prepared queries and the input will be "SQL" escaped, not filtered.

The problem arises when you don't properly escape the input and it get interpolated as part of the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

PDO `prepare()` statement is not for preventing the attacker from inserting bad queries.

This function hast just made it easy to realise what type of data is being inserted in query.

> There has a lot of way to make this function fool

**It will be the good try (practice) to validate and sanitize the data before participating in query**